# jquery ui datepicker day highlight is not working when using two date picker

Tags: jquery

there are two jquery ui date picker i have where second date picker date want to changes with respect to first datepicker. I already got solution for it from here. But when i click date 4 in first date picker it also select 4 in second date picker and date before 4 in second date picker disabled. then i click on date 3 in first, on second 3 enabled but day highligt stay in date 4 only when double clicking on date 3 in first then only day highligt came to date3. Can u help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please can you post some code to show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                                var deliverydatetext = $('#deliverydatepicker').datepicker('getDate');
                                deliverydatetext.setDate(deliverydatetext.getDate());
                                $('#pickupdatepicker').datepicker('setDate', deliverydatetext);
                                $('#pickupdatepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', deliverydatetext);

Comment: in second date picker

Comment: var newdate = deliverydatetext;

Comment: minDate: newdate,

Answer (score 0):

infirst date picker

onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

```
 var deliverydatetext = $('#deliverydatepicker').datepicker('getDate'));
```

deliverydatetext.setDate(deliverydatetext.getDate());

$('#pickupdatepicker').datepicker('setDate', deliverydatetext);

$('#pickupdatepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', deliverydatetext);

in second datepicker

Answer (score 0):

var newdate = deliverydatetext;

$('#pickupdatepicker').datepicker(
                        {

```
                        numberOfMonths: 1,
                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        minDate: newdate,
                        beforeShowDay: unavailablepickupdates,
```